# Is there a way to use Azure Logic app to read an outlook email which has a link that dowloads a csv file and then store the file in a storage blob?

Tags: http, outlook, azure-logic-apps

I was trying to figure out how to use a logic app to download a file from the link provided in an outlook email! Any suggestions would be of great help!

I’ve tried using the HTTP connector so far and was wondering if this use case can be implemented using the logic app

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use Azure Logic app to read an outlook email which has a link that dowloads a csv file and then store the file in a storage blob?

Yes, you can do by following below design:

[image]

Then:
[image]

Get Attachement (V2)2:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Full design:

[image]

Created a storage account:

[image]

After new emails comes with attachment:

[image]

Now logic app runs:
[image]
[image]
In storage account after logic apps runs:
[image]

[image]

Code View :

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Create_blob_(V2)_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@base64ToBinary(body('Get_Attachment_(V2)_2')?['contentBytes'])",
                            "headers": {
                                "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderPath": "/rithwik",
                                "name": "@body('Get_Attachment_(V2)_2')?['name']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_Attachment_(V2)_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "contentTransfer": {
                                "transferMode": "Chunked"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Get_Attachment_(V2)_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/codeless/v1.0/me/messages/@{encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['id'])}/attachments/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['id'])}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@triggerBody()?['attachments']",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Foreach"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "fetch": {
                        "method": "get",
                        "pathTemplate": {
                            "template": "/v3/Mail/OnNewEmail"
                        },
                        "queries": {
                            "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": true,
                            "folderPath": "Inbox",
                            "importance": "Any",
                            "includeAttachments": false
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "subscribe": {
                        "body": {
                            "NotificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                        },
                        "method": "post",
                        "pathTemplate": {
                            "template": "/GraphMailSubscriptionPoke/$subscriptions"
                        },
                        "queries": {
                            "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": true,
                            "folderPath": "Inbox",
                            "importance": "Any"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnectionNotification"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1b83a/resourceGroups/v-rbojja-Mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1c2/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-/resourceGroups/bojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```